# Count number of | per column in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a 5 column by 100 row data frame. I want to count the number of pipe symbols `|` occurring in each column.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    c("A", "B", "C", "B", "B"),
    c("|", "W", "G", "|", "D"),
    c("Q", "D", "F", "|", "F"),
    c("Q", "|", "|", "|", "Q")),
    5, 5, byrow=T)
)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  A  B  C  B  B
3  |  W  G  |  D
4  Q  D  F  |  F
5  Q  |  |  |  Q
```

I'd like a result showing 1 pipe in column 1, 1 pipe in column 2, 1 pipe in column 3, 3 pipes in column 4, 0 pipes in column 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each string is just single character, you can do a simple `sapply`:

```
# turning the example data you provided into a data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    c("A", "B", "C", "B", "B"),
    c("|", "W", "G", "|", "D"),
    c("Q", "D", "F", "|", "F"),
    c("Q", "|", "|", "|", "Q")),
    5, 5, byrow=T)
)

# calculation you want
sapply(df, function(x) sum(x == "|"))

# result = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is using `colSums()` on Dan Y's data frame.

```
colSums(df == "|")

V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
 1  1  1  3  0
```